# very high max response and error when submit looping form submission

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

so my requirement is to run 90 concurrent user doing mutiple scenario (15 scenario)simultenously for 30 minutes in virtual macine.so some of the threads i use concurrent thread group and normal thread group.

now my issue is
1)after i execute all 15 scenarios, my max response for each scenario displayed very high (>40sec). is there any suggestion to reduce this high max response?

2)one of the scenario is submit web form, there is no issue if submit only one, however during the 90 concurrent user execution, some of submit web form will get 500 error code. is the error is because i use looping to achieve 30 min duration?

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to reduce the response time you need to find the reason for this high response time, the reasons could be in:

   - lack of resources like CPU, RAM, etc. - make sure to monitor resources consumption using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
   - incorrect configuration of the middleware (application server, database, etc.), all these components need to be properly tuned for high loads, for example if you set maximum number of connections on the application server to 10 and you have 90 threads - the 80 threads will be queuing up waiting for the next available executor, the same applies to the database [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)
   - use a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) to inspect what's going on under the hood and why the slowest functions are that slow, it might be the case your application algorithms are not [efficient enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)
2. If your test succeeds with single thread and fails under the load - it definitely indicates the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), try increasing the load gradually and see how many users application can support without performance degradation and/or throwing errors. [HTTP Status codes 5xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) indicate server-side errors so it also worth inspecting your application logs for more insights